# Referencing a StaticResource in another DynamicResource

Tags: wpf

If I change some resource used as StaticResource then all the controls which referring to is affected.

And it does not in case the resource is referred as DynamicResource.

But how about some resource referred as StaticResource in a DynamicResource?

```
        <Color x:Key="Color">#000000</Color>
        
        <LinearGradientBrush  x:Key="GradientBrush" EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="0,1" >
            <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource Color}"  Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource Color}"  Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <DrawingBrush x:Key="TabItemBrush" >
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="{StaticResource GradientBrush}">
                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0 100 100 100"/>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                </GeometryDrawing>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>
```

```
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Grid x:Name="Root">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" >
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(DrawingBrush.Drawing).(GeometryDrawing.Brush).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(DrawingBrush.Drawing).(GeometryDrawing.Brush).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{DynamicResource TabItemBrush}">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"  VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header"  
                                                  Margin="12,2,12,2"  RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

`Border` in `TabItem` refers `TabItemBrush` using `DynamicResource`.

`TabItemBrush` refers `GradientBrush` using  `StaticResource`.

`GradientBrush` refers `Color` using `StaticResource`.

```
    <StackPanel>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="AAA" >AAA</TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="BBB" >BBB</TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="CCC" >BBB</TabItem>
        </TabControl>
        <Border Background="{DynamicResource GradientBrush}" Height="1000" Width="1000"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

I thought that all of `TabItem` change to same color when I change a selected item in `TabControl` because all of resources is referred as StaticResource except `TabItemBrush`.

But only the color of selected item is blue and the others red.

Moreover if i change all the StaticResource to DynamicResource, it works incorrectly ( all red or all blue).

Why StaticResource works as if it is not shared and DynamicResource as shared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your question very difficult to understand. However, I think you are confused because you are not understanding the difference between `StaticResource` and `DynamicResource`.

- As the names suggest, `StaticResource` references will/can never change (they are static).
- Resources referenced using `StaticResource` are resolved only once at compile-time.
- As the names suggest, `DynamicResource` references can change (they are dynamic).
- Resources referenced using `DynamicResource` are resolved at runtime.
- Since `StaticResource` references are resolved at compile-time, the XAML parser can avoid the overhead of creating an intermediate lookup expression (which is then executed at runtime).
  This is why you should always avoid `DynamicResource` with the goal to improve the application's performance.
- `StaticResource` does not allow forward references, whereas `DynamicResource` does - but the forward reference aspect doesn't matter in your context.

> "If I change some resource used as StaticResource then all the
> controls which referring to is affected."

This is definitely *not correct*. You can't change resources referenced as `StaticResource` and then observe that those changes update the referencing objects - this can't have never happened (see explanation of the fundamental characteristics above).
You probably meant something different here.

> "I thought that all of TabItem change to same color when I change a selected >item in TabControl because all of resources is referred as StaticResource >except TabItemBrush.
>
> But only the color of selected item is blue and the others red."

This is the correct behavior. You have defined the `VisualState` objects for "Selected" and "Unselected" with the `VisualStateManager`. According to these states clicking a `TabItem` will modify the `Background` of the selected item to blue and all other unselected items to red.

> "Moreover if i change all the StaticResource to DynamicResource, it works >incorrectly ( all red or all blue)."

Here comes in the special behavior of the XAML engine in context of animations: it will freeze the `Storyboard`.
This means, all participating child instances like `AnimationTimeline` (e.g., `ColorAnimation`), or `Animatable` types in general, are frozen and therefore *not changeable* (they all inherit `Freezable`).

As a consequence, all referenced resources like `Brush` must be static and known at compile-time: you can't reference resources using `DynamicResource` if the referencing instance needs to be frozen.
Resources used in a `Storyboard` must be referenced as `StaticResource`.

Now, given the case that an element, for example a `Border`, uses `DynamicResource` to reference a resource that itself contains references to other resources:

- If the element uses `DynamicResource` to reference a pure static resource (a resource that doesn't itself references other resources using `DynamicReference`), then the XAML engine will optimize the reference by treating it as a `StaticResource`, to avoid the overhead, and store it in the internal lookup table for the static resources (remember, `StaticResource` is much cheaper in terms of performance costs than looking up a `DynamicResource`). This resource can be targeted by a `Storyboard` animation as it is now static:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary>
  <Color x:Key="Color">#000000</Color>
        
  <!-- Resource is treated as a static resource -->
  <LinearGradientBrush  x:Key="GradientBrush" EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="0,1" >
    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource Color}"  Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource Color}"  Offset="1" />
  </LinearGradientBrush>
</ResourceDictionary>

<!-- The lookup behavior is optimized to StaticResource.
     A Storyboard therefore will be able to animate the Background resource. 
-->
<Border Background="{DynamicResource GradientBrush}" />
```

- If the resource that an element references is itself referencing at least one resource using `DynamicResource`, then the reference will remain dynamic and will prevent e.g., the Storyboard from being frozen and the animation won't work:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary>
  <Color x:Key="Color">#000000</Color>
        
  <!-- Resource is treated as a dynamic resource, 
       because it contains at least one DynamicResource reference. 
  -->
  <LinearGradientBrush  x:Key="GradientBrush" EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="0,1" >
    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource Color}"  Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource Color}"  Offset="1" />
  </LinearGradientBrush>
</ResourceDictionary>

<!-- The lookup behavior is now DynamicResource and not optimized. 
     A Storyboard won't be able to animate the properties of the resource as it can't be frozen. 
 -->
<Border Background="{DynamicResource GradientBrush}" />
```

Another effect you ecounter is that all items have the same Background when you select a TabItem.
This is related to the way the XAML engine handles resources. Referenceing a resource using StaticResource, results in the resource being shared by default.

You have two solutions to fix this issue:

1. Declare each participating resource of the static reference as non-shared by setting the `x:Shared` attribute to `false`:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary>
  <Color x:Key="Color"
         x:Shared="False">#000000</Color>

  <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GradientBrush" 
                       x:Shared="False" 
                       EndPoint="0,0" 
                       StartPoint="0,1" >
    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource Color}"  Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource Color}"  Offset="1" />
  </LinearGradientBrush>
</ResourceDictionary>

<Border Background="{StaticResource GradientBrush}" />
```

2. Alternatively, define the animated resource as inline. This way each `TabItem` border will have its own/non-shared `Brush` resource:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary>
  <Color x:Key="Color">#000000</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>

<Border>
  <Border.Background>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="0,1" >
      <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource Color}"  Offset="0" />
      <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource Color}"  Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
  </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

Comment: I found that all items be same color if i change ```Background``` of ```Border``` to ```StaticResource```. It is relevant to VSM freezing?

Comment: No this has a different reason. i have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is helpful. But I wonder that "This is definitely not correct." which you said might be not right. I think it may be because of my poor english skill. But the resource referred as ```StaticResource``` is changed and effect others, isn't ii?

Comment: I found that If I add ```x:Shared = "False"``` like above, then it works well even if I change ```StaticResource``` in ```GradientStop``` to ```DynamicResource```.  Then is it still right that It is relevant to VSM freezing?

Comment: Maybe it's your not do good English. But if you change a resource the referencing element that uses StaticResource don't see any changes. StatucResource is only evaluated once. So when you say that *"the resource referred as StaticResource is changed and effect others"*, then this is wrong. There are two effects: a Storyboaed that needs to be frozen by the XAML engine and the way the engine manages instances of the resources.

Comment: Storyboard can't reference resources using DynamicResource and StaticResources are shared. The brush resource is used for every TabItem. Animating the brush for one item results in changing the brush for the other items - the effectively use the same brush.

Comment: So all items having the same color is the  result the resource sharing behavior.

Comment: *"Moreover if i change all the StaticResource to DynamicResource, it works >incorrectly ( all red or all blue)."* - this is freezing related.